# False flag multibit errors on highest populated DIMM socket on second CPU of Sunfire x2200. Faulty CPU or faulty motherboard?

Tags: memory, central-processing-unit, hardware

I'm testing 2GB ECC Registered DIMMs in a Sunfire x2200. Recently the system event log (SEL) began logging Multibit Errors on the highest populated DIMM socket on CPU1. With 8 DIMMs on CPU1, the SEL claims multibit errors on CPU1DIMM7. With 4 DIMMs on CPU1, it claims multibit errors on CPU1DIMM3. This doesn't happen at all when only CPU0 is populated. After noticing this pattern, I began trying out DIMMs that I know to be in working condition (verified by another working system), but the outcome is still the same.

To me, this says there's a problem with either CPU1, or the motherboard. But we require both CPUs for production and I'd rather not write the whole machine off as unusable. Aside from swapping out CPUs, and retesting the DIMMs in that CPUs DIMM sockets, is there any way to confirm that the CPU is faulty, rather than the motherboard? I'm afraid there might be some sort troubleshooting process for this situation that I'm unfamiliar with. If so, please enlighten me.

Comment: What about swapping CPU0 and CPU1? If it's the CPU, then the errors would move to CPU0 instead.

Comment: I haven't tried that with this specific machine, however a co-worker has informed me that they've tried that in the past (we've seen this problem more than a couple times) and it didn't help the situation. I realize that this implies that the CPU is fine... which means the problem is between the CPU socket and the DIMM sockets I guess.

Comment: Just move them around in a structured way.

Comment: Time for a new board. That model in particular is relatively cheap from a quick search, so that shouldn't be *too* much of a problem. I'm afraid you'll never know the exact problem...motherboards can be fickle things.